# FLASK - server could not understand request (uploading audio file)

Tags: python, flask, request

I built a flask app to be able to send audio (.wav, mp3) file to the ML model and make a prediction out of it. The problem is that request.files does not work. "The browser or proxy sent a request that this server could not understand".

Does anyone have any idea what is missing/wrong?

Flask app:

```
@app.route('/')
def upload_file():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route("/prediction", methods=["GET","POST"])
def prediction():
    file = request.files['file']
    image = create_spectogram(file)
    pred = predict(model, image)
    result = create_result(pred)
    return jsonify(result)
```

upload.html:

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/prediction" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your prediction function receives both GET and POST requests you have to handle each case separately. As you don’t have `request.form` when you receive GET request.

I would suggest you to add a condition in your function.

```
def prediction():
        if request.method == 'POST':
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass FileStorage object to the model. 
You have to store the file somewhere so you can use it.

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
app.config['IMAGE_UPLOADS'] = '/path/'

file = request.files['file']
filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
file.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], filename))
```

Now use the filename as a path to show where your actual file is that you want to use.

```
actual_file = 'path/' + filename
```

You can pass actual_file to your ML model. Hope this helps.